# I have two columns in table that I need to concat and make first of month

Tags: date

select distinct
cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [year], 105) + '-' + convert(varchar(10), [month], 105)) as FirstDay

The columns are year and month and I want to concatenate and then make them the first day of the month so it would be 2021-01-01 2021-02-01 2021-03-01 etc..........